# Cannot access fragmentclass file for android.support.v4.fragment not found

Tags: android, androidx, android-glide

I am trying to do this in android studio:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(url.get((int)(5)))).into(imageview6);
```

but it shows the following error

> *error: cannot access Fragment
> Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(url.get((int)(5)))).into(imageview6);*

> *Cannot access fragmentclass file for android.support.v4.fragment not found*

I have tried Migrate to AndroidX but it simply says "no usage found".

Comment: `Glide.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse(url.get((int)(5)))).into(imageview6);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` to get the context in `Fragment` class.

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Final the code will be

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse(url.get((int)(5)))).into(imageview6);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks A lot!. But migrating to AndroidX and making a new file called gradle.properties and adding 
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true to the file solved it

Comment: Please update the answer with the solution from the first comment, That must be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the old glide dependencies that's why I got this error. try to use the newly updated dependency. That works for me!